# Scala & XSBT - share part of build classpath with project classpath

Tags: scala, sbt

First of all I'm very new to Scala, SBT and Vaadin.

I'm trying to make an Scala & Vaadin application with Timeline addon. I had to put Timeline jar (unmanaged dependency) and Vaadin dependency under *build* project (`project/`) so I can compile it during build (well, by calling *vaadin* task). How can I merge `vaadin-timeline-agpl-3.0-1.2.3.jar` and Vaadin dependency into vaadinTest project without duplicating jar and dependency? Below is my project structure. Thank you. By the way, I already tried existing Vaadin plugins but they suck (all I need to do is to compile widgetset).

This is my project structure:

```
vaadinTest/
    project/
        lib/vaadin-timeline-agpl-3.0-1.2.3.jar
        build.sbt
        ProjectBuild.scala
    src/
```

`vaadinTest/project/build.sbt:`

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "com.google.gwt" % "gwt-user" % "2.4.0",
    "com.google.gwt" % "gwt-dev" % "2.4.0",
    "com.vaadin" % "vaadin" % "6.7.4"
)
```

`vaadinTest/project/ProjectBuild.scala:`

```
import com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler
import sbt._
import Keys._

object ProjectBuild extends Build {
    val deps = Seq(
        "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-server" % "8.1.0.RC5",
        "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-webapp" % "8.1.0.RC5",
        "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-servlet" % "8.1.0.RC5",
    )
    val vaadinTest = Project(
        "vaadinTest", file("."), Defaults.defaultSettings
            ++ Seq(libraryDependencies ++= deps)
            ++ Seq(vaadinTask)
    )

    val vaadin = TaskKey[Unit]("vaadin")
    val vaadinTask = vaadin := {
        Compiler.main(Array("-war", "src/main/webapp/VAADIN/widgetsets",
            "com.vaadin.addon.timeline.gwt.TimelineWidgetSet"))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question mentions a "plugin" project, but I can't see that project in your project structure or `ProjectBuild.scala`?

In any case, you can add additional directories to your classpath by modifying the `dependencyClasspath` setting. This is documented [here](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Getting-Started-Library-Dependencies) (see the "Unmanaged dependencies" section).

Comment: I made a typo, _plugin_ should be _build_. Fixed. `project/` directory is another sbt project (_build definition_ project, https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Getting-Started-Full-Def). I'll try to mess with `dependencyClasspath`. Thank you.